# What is the best way to detect anomalies in exception count, from logs, in azure

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have an asp.net application deployed in azure. This generates plenty of logs, some of which are exceptions. I do have a query in Log Analytics Workspace that picks up exceptions from logs.

I would like to know what is the best and/or cheapest way to detect anomalies in the exception count over a time period.

For example, if the average number of exceptions for every hour is N (based on information collected over the past 1 month or so), and if average goes  > N+20 at any time (checked every 1 hour or so), then I need to be notified.

N would be dynamically changing based on trend.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what is the best and/or cheapest way to detect anomalies in the exception count over a time period.

Yes, we can achieve this by following steps:

1. Store the average value in a **Stored Query Result** in Azure.

   Using stored query result

```
 .set stored_query_result
```

These are some limitations to keep the result. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results) for detailed information.

##### Note: The stored query result will be available only 24 hours.

#### Workaround Follows

1. Set the Stored query result

```
# here i am using  Stored query result to store the average value of trace message count for 5 hours
.set stored_query_result average <| 
traces
| summarize events = count() by bin(timestamp, 5h)
| summarize avg(events)
```

[image]
2. Once Query Result Set you can use the Stored Query Result value in another KQL Query (The stored value was available till 24 hours)

```
# Retrieve the stored Query Result 
stored_query_result(<StoredQueryResultName>) | 
Query follows as per your need
```

3. Schedule the alert.

Comment: This is interesting, will try soon. Would it be possible to use the previous/current stored_query_result value in the new stored_query_result value calculation?